How to install bot when using message extension action
I have a message extension app with bot in it. When I add the app in personal. And when in the teams channel, if I used the message extension. It should pop up for installation. For that I have used this bit of code from the github repo.
But when I click the button. It's give Unable to reach app. Please try again.
function GetJustInTimeCardAttachment() {
    return CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
        actions: [
            {
                type: 'Action.Submit',
                title: 'Continue',
                data: { msteams: { justInTimeInstall: true } }
            }
        ],
        body: [
            {
                text: 'Looks like you have not used Action Messaging Extension app in this team/chat. Please click **Continue** to add this app.',
                type: 'TextBlock',
                wrap: true
            }
        ],
        type: 'AdaptiveCard',
        version: '1.0'
    });
}


"Unable to reach app. Please try again." suggests that there might be an issue with the bot's endpoint or the way the app is registered or configured in Teams. Could you please verify that the bot is registered correctly in the Microsoft Bot Framework and that the bot ID in the app manifest matches the one registered.
Endpoint Accessibility? Verify that the bot's endpoint URL is accessible and that there are no issues with the server hosting the bot service also verify the app manifest to ensure that the msteams property and justInTimeInstall attribute are correctly configured?

Have you verified the above checkpoints?
